# SegmentedControlStyle deprecated in iOS 7 and later (8.4) | Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, deprecated

I got this problem the other day. I'm new at **Xcode**, and I had the task
of upgrade the code used for an app in **iOS 6.1 to 8.4**, but there are so many
**deprecated methods**. I solved most of them, but I just simply can't find how to solve these ones, or for what code I can change them... Does anyone has an idea?

Thank you so much!!

Both, the "**segmentedControlStyle**" and the "**UISegmentedControlStyleBar**" are deprecated.

This is the line causing me problems.

**showControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;**

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900034/use-ios-6-style-segmented-control-in-ios-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `segmentedControlStyle` property has been deprecated because in iOS 7 it *has no effect*.

Instances of a `UISegmentedControl` now only have one style, so you can remove that line entirely. If your appearance is undesirable, you'll need to tweak further to achieve the intended look.

Comment: It seems that it worked, thank you, now... this is happening, when I debug, this line doesn't seem to be failing.  

**[self.clientImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_client.imageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];**

but throws this error: 

**[UIImageView sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbe937a88b0** :c

Comment: Look closely: why does the method you're calling start with `sd_`?

Comment: Aaaah! it due to the version that I'm using, the one with out de _sd is deprecated in this version (3.7.0).

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UISegmentedControlStyle

Apple said:

> The styles of the segmented control.
>
> Use tintColor instead.