# how to create custom NavigationBar subclass and add multi Item in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I want create `UINavigationBar` custom subclass with multi items. but I don't know about this.

also I want to get this custom `NavigationBar` in `UIViewControllers` and change it.

please guide me :
1- how to create custom `NavigationBar` subclass with items.
2- how to get this custom Nav and change items in it.

this is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
  ViewController *rootView = [[ViewController alloc]init];

  UINavigationController *navi = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[NavBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
  navi.viewControllers = @[rootView];
  self.window.rootViewController = navi;

  [window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

**NavBar.m**

```
#import "NavBar.h"

@implementation NavBar
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    [self setup];
  }
  return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
  if (self) {
    [self setup];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)setup {
  [self setupBackground];
}

- (void)setupBackground {
  self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  self.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];

  // make navigation bar overlap the content
  self.translucent = YES;
  self.opaque = NO;

  // remove the default background image by replacing it with a clear image
  [self setBackgroundImage:[self.class maskedImage] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

  // remove defualt bottom shadow
  [self setShadowImage: [UIImage new]];
}

+ (UIImage *)maskedImage {
  const CGFloat colorMask[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};
  UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-white-pixel-bg.jpg"];
  return [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(img.CGImage, colorMask)];
}
/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a `UISegmentedControl`.

You can either add this to a `UINavigationBar` in a storyboard or [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688160/how-to-programmatically-add-a-uisegmentedcontrol-to-a-container-view).

Definitely give the documentation on [`UISegmentedControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html)'s a look as well

Answer (score 0):

To get your custom NavigationBar into your viewController, you should have it in a `UINavigationController` subclass

**CustomNavigationController.m**

```
@implementation CustomNavigationController


-(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar
{
     return [[MYCustomNavBar alloc]init];
}
```

though actually you don't need to do this if you'd just like to change the appearance of a normal navigationbar.. you can do this in the `viewDidLoad` of your custom navigationController

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f],NSFontAttributeName,[UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:dictionary];

}
```

Then when adding your viewController, you need to wrap it in the navigation controller

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

     // other launching code

    SomeViewController *viewController = [[SomeViewController alloc]init];
    CustomNavigationController *navigationController = [[CustomNavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**SomeViewController.m**

In your viewController subclass you can access the navigation bar like this

`self.navigationController.navigationBar`

However to add different items to your navigation bar, you can use

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` and `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`

To have more than one button / item in either the left or right section, you can create a custom view, and add that as your bar button item...

```
UIView *containerView = [UIView alloc]initWithFrame: // etc...

// create your items`

[containerView addSubview:item1];
[containerView addSubview:item2]; // etc...

// then add the custom view as the navigation item..

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:containerView];
```

Alternatively if you don't want a bespoke container view and are happy with uniform / dynamic spacing between your items you can use

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[item1,item2];
```

Thanks @Fawkes for the addition.

Comment: what about using directly self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems without container view?

Comment: also true, though I've often found this better for custom spacing etc... this wasn't defined as a requirement though so i'll add it to my answer. cheers.